# dig/nslookup gives back a servfail error

Tags: networking, dns, bind

For the past couple of days I've been walking into a certain problem I can't seem to fix. Currently I only have 1 machine in my network and it's just a RHEL 8 server with DNS and other services installed and configured. The problem is when I try to dig or use nslookup I get a servfail error. Can anyone spot if I have configured anything wrong?

```
Server:     192.168.50.100
Address:    192.168.50.100#53

** server can't find salt.jenna.af: SERVFAIL
```

Dig output:

```
[root@salt named]# dig salt.jenna.af

; <<>> DiG 9.11.36-RedHat-9.11.36-3.el8_6.1 <<>> salt.jenna.af
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 29195
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 13c6c973e66bb6eed834a40363600d050510d121b2e7ee40 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;salt.jenna.af.         IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.50.100#53(192.168.50.100)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 31 10:59:33 PDT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70
```

Below are my /etc/named.conf and /var/named/jenna.af.db (named.empty) files.

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; any;};

};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "jenna.af" IN {
        type master;
        file "jenna.af.db";
        allow-query {any; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

```
$TTL 3H
@       IN SOA   salt.jenna.af. root.jenna.af. (
                                        311022  ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
salt    IN      A       192.168.50.100
client  IN      A       192.168.50.200
```

If anything is unclear or more information is needed I'm happy to provide it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention your server is RHEL 8. Your file names and some contents look unfamiliar, but I don't know if that is RHEL doing things differently than Ubuntu or what.

Since your server is not Ubuntu, your question is off topic here. But anyway...

I think this line:

```
@       IN SOA   salt.jenna.af. root.jenna.af. (
```

should be this:

```
@       IN SOA   jenna.af. root.jenna.af. (
```

and it should have an ip address defined. I also do not know about using localhost the way you have. Overall, I am suggesting this:

```
$TTL 3H
@       IN SOA   jenna.af. root.jenna.af. (
                                        311022  ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN      A       192.168.50.100 
;
@       IN      NS      salt.jenna.af.
salt    IN      A       192.168.50.100
client  IN      A       192.168.50.200
```

You should also try the named-checkzone program.
In the end, I don't know more than the information [the Ubuntu Serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns) provides.